# Live updating graph from increasing amount of csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, watchdog

I need to analyse some spectral data in real-time and plot it as a self-updating graph.
The program I use outputs a text file every two seconds.

Usually I do the analysis after gathering the data and the code works just fine. I create a dataframe, where each csv file represents a column. The problem is, with several thousands of csv files, the import becomes very slow and creating a dataframe out of all the csv files takes usually more than half an hour.
Below the code for creating the dataframe from multiple csv files.

```
    ''' import, append and concat files into one dataframe '''
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, filter + "*.txt")) # path to the files by joining path and file name
    all_files.sort(key=os.path.getmtime)
    data_frame = []
    name = []
    for file in (all_files):
        creation_time = os.path.getmtime(file)
        readible_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(creation_time)
        df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0, header=None, sep='\t', engine='python', decimal=",", skiprows = 15)
        df.rename(columns={1: readible_date}, inplace=True)
        data_frame.append(df)
        full_spectra = pd.concat(data_frame, axis=1)
    for column in full_spectra.columns:
        time_step = column - full_spectra.columns[0]
        minutes = time_step.total_seconds()/60
        name.append(minutes)    
    full_spectra.columns = name
    return full_spectra
```

The solution I thought of was using the watchdog module and everytime a new textfile is created it gets appended as a new column to the existing dataframe and the updated dataframe is plotted. Because then, I do not need to loop over all csv files all the time.

[I found a very nice example on how to use watchdog here](https://gist.github.com/mastro35/0c433bb13d0efa347ce0fbf8ec1cb225)

My problem is, I could not find a solution how after detecting the new file with watchdog, to read it and append it to the existing dataframe.

A minimalistic example code should look something like this:

```
def latest_filename():
"""a function that checks within a directoy for new textfiles"""
    return(filename)

df = pd.DataFrame() #create a dataframe

newdata  = pd.read_csv(latest_filename) #The new file is found by watchdog

df["newcolumn"] = newdata["desiredcolumn"] #append the new data as column

df.plot() #plot the data
```

The plotting part should be easy and my thoughts were to [adapt the code presented here](https://pythonprogramming.net/live-graphs-matplotlib-tutorial/). I am more concerned with the self-updating dataframe.

I appreciate any help or other solutions that would solve my issue!